# symfony: defining logouts for multiple firewalls

Tags: php, security, symfony

I need to define logout paths for multiple firewalls in symfony 2. How do I configure my routing.yml file to allow for this?

```
security.yml

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        demo:
            pattern: ^/demo
            logout:
                path: /demo/logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

        admin:
            pattern: /admin
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~            

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/demo, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I have tried the adding the following to my yaml file but I get a 404 on /demo/logout.

routing.yml

```
logout:
    path: /admin/logout
    path: /demo/logout
```

one final related question: Can I define a single logout path for multiple firewalls?

Comment: Of course you can, but using single logout path for multiple firewalls mean your firewalls share the same security context.

Comment: can you show some examples please?

Answer (score 0):

In your routing.yml, put:

```
logout_admin:
    path: /admin/logout

logout_demo:
    path: /demo/logout
```

You can use any name to register your variables.